# Sql referencing a WITH clause entity from the SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

## Overview

I have 2 sets of filepaths, the filepaths all contain a UID as *part of* the filename.

- The *fullpath* set is in a table **DirFiles**, and these filenames change from external forces, but the UID part never changes.
- The *location* set is in a table **BrainAttachments**, which is the update target.

*I have to make some XML to do the update, so this is not about a typical table update. I am trying to build a query.*

### Data Layout

```
-- contains various file paths, grouped as sets by uname
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DirFiles](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [uname] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [fullpath] [varchar](300) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- file attachments table, 'location' field contains a file path
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BrainAttachments](
    [brain_guid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [guid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [location] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  ...more...
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

### Filepaths

The DirFiles table is fed a set of paths using a uname of 'slickmacs'
Paths take the following form:

```
ROOT QUALIFIER           | MODULE | SIGNATURE                     | BACKWARDS PATH                      | FILE     | UID            | EXT
C:\SlickEdit2007\macros\@\__appact\cmd appact_slickhelp()-typeless --__appact--macros--Slickedit2007--C--__appact.e.7946371600659277.#+!
```

### Use Case: Rename

Everything in this path is subject to a change except the Root Qualifier and the UID. Upon Rename, we want to find the **BrainAttachment**
with the UID and Root Qualifier for further processing.
The inputs to the further processing are the attachment guid and the new, renamed path from **DirFiles**.

### Obstacles: Avoid layered views, very bad on performance. Avoid temp_tables. So we use WITH clauses...

Attempting a view here...

```
-- query currently executes in 2-3 secs WITHOUT the field I desire
;WITH
-- slickmacs: getting a list of all paths under 'slickmacs' and 
-- extracting the UID, aka 'zdot'
-- 7000 records under uname='slickmacs'
slickmacs(fullpath,zdot) as
(
  SELECT     fullpath,dbo.fnPathZdotPart(fullpath)
  FROM         dbo.DirFiles
  WHERE     (uname = 'slickmacs')
),
-- find attachments that qualify, but their location is not in slickmacs
-- 10,000 records in BrainAttachments WHERE 1=1
location_notin(guid,location) as
(
  SELECT     guid,location
  FROM       dbo.BrainAttachments BA
  WHERE     (NOT EXISTS
                            (SELECT     fullpath
                              FROM          slickmacs
                              WHERE      (BA.location = fullpath)))
  AND (SUBSTRING(location, 1, 26) = 'C:\SlickEdit2007\macros\@\')
  AND (SUBSTRING(dbo.fnPathFileExt(location), 1, 1) = '#')
  AND (brain_guid = dbo.GuidOfSlickKeys())
),
-- I am trying to 'float up' the fullpath here so I can 
-- get at it below in my SELECT
location_notin_fp(guid,fullpath) as
(
  select guid
                ,(select fullpath from slickmacs
                  where zdot=dbo.fnPathZdotPart(LNI.location)
                ) as fullpath
  from location_notin LNI
)
-- PROBLEM: Here for the second field, I want the fullpath
SELECT     guid

-- METHOD 1: takes 2 minutes
--                ,(select fullpath from location_notin_fp
--                  where guid=BA.guid
--                ) as fullpath

-- METHOD 2: takes 2 minutes
--                ,(select fullpath from slickmacs
--                  where zdot=dbo.fnPathZdotPart(BA.location)
--                ) as fullpath

FROM       dbo.BrainAttachments BA
-- ALTERNATE METHODS: Gets errors

-- METHOD 3: Error: identifiers not found: dbo.BrainAttachments.guid,location_notin_fp.guid
--INNER JOIN location_notin_fp LNO ON dbo.BrainAttachments.guid=location_notin_fp.guid

-- METHOD 4: Error: identifiers not found: dbo.BrainAttachments.guid
--INNER JOIN (select * from location_notin_fp ) as LNF ON dbo.BrainAttachments.guid=LNF.guid

-- METHOD 5: Error: ambiguous column name: guid
--INNER JOIN (select * from location_notin_fp ) as LNF ON BA.guid=LNF.guid


-- get where location not in fullpaths and location.zdot in fullpaths.zdot
WHERE
(EXISTS
  (SELECT *  FROM location_notin
    WHERE      (BA.guid = guid)
  )
)
AND (EXISTS
  (SELECT fullpath FROM slickmacs
    WHERE      (zdot=dbo.fnPathZdotPart(BA.location))
  )
)
```

### Summary

So basically I have a computation f(x) that gets the UID from filepaths in two tables, but I do not want to execute that function count(T1)*count(T2) times, and I dont want to use temp tables.

In English, "Give me all the attachments whose names have changed on the disk, given the UID part of the filename remains constant throughout, and do it quickly"

Comment: At least you need to add clustered indexes and indexes on the searched columns. 2nd you are wrong regarding temp tables, sometimes when sql server struggles to get fine execution plan, variable or temporary table is only solution to get proper speed.

Comment: @Farfarak Yes, I know about temp tables, but I put that in there because I want to know how to jump this particular fence, so I don't want the 'just build a gate' answers. IOW, how to get `fullpath` into my `SELECT`.